# What is Naruto saying in this video?

Tags: anime, transcription

I need the Japanese transcription.

Here's the link to the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IXWhFAD4SQ#t=2m04s (from 02:04 to 02:42).

Here's what I could understand so far (mistakes included... I also didn't understand Naruto's first word):

ナルト「？」

ミナト「ナルト！」

ナルト「なんで？なんで？なんで息子の俺に九尾なんか封印したんだよ！おかげで俺ってばすっげえ大変だぞ！暁日柄寝られて！。。。」

ミナト「すまなかった。いろいろ大変だったんだよな。息子のお前につらい思いばかりさせてしまった俺が父親ヅラして謝るのも違うかな。」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ナルト「**(な)んでだよ？**」

ミナト「ナルト！」

ナルト「なんで？なんで？なんで息子の俺に、九尾なんか封印したんだよ！？おかげで俺ってば、すげえ大変**で**！**[暁]{あかつき}から狙われて、そいつらと戦って、それで、それで、すげえ寂しくて、我慢して・・・**。」

ミナト「すまなかった。**ずっと一人にして**。大変**だったよな**。息子のお前につらい思いばかりさせてしまった俺が、父親**[面]{づら}**して謝るのも、違うかな。」

Comment: ありがとうございました！ ;)

Comment: @Madara I don't understand your edit suggestion. Naruto is saying "それで、**それで**", not "それで、**そして**."

Comment: If you listen to it again, he says "sore de, soshite,"

Comment: 泣きながら話している設定なので、かすれていて聞こえにくいかもしれませんけど、何度聞いても、「それで、それで、」と言っています。それに、「それで、そして、」というのは、おかしいです。No matter how many times I listen to it, it sounds as それで、それで、 to my native ears.

Comment: My bad, then. I was wrong. Thank you again my friend... Since the translation also said "And then" I thought maybe "soshite" was the correct word... ;)